# Django tutorial on pythonanywhere: trouble running the django-admin shell

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pythonanywhere

*(Django version 1.9, Python version 3.4.3, using virtual env made with* `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4 django19`*)*

I've been following the Django tutorial very closely, without any problems up til part 5:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/

although, strictly speaking, the problem isn't to do with part 5, but bear with me. I'm following the tutorial in the pythonanywhere framework, because eventually I would like to host a website there. Therefore, I am also following the 'Following the Django tutorial' offered by pythonanywhere:

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/FollowingTheDjangoTutorial

although my problem isn't anticipated in the advice for part 5 in the tutorial. Now the problem- at the point in the Django tutorial which reads:

> To check if the bug really exists, using the Admin create a question whose date lies in the future and check the method using the [shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-shell)

Following the link to the shell, I try (as instructed in the link) to run:

```
django-admin shell --plain
```

However I get the following error message

```
(django19)19:11 ~/mysite $ django-admin shell --plain
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 391, in execute saved_locale = translation.get_language()
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 176, in get_language
return _trans.get_language()
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
if settings.USE_I18N:
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
 % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 360, in run_from_argv
connections.close_all()
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 230, in close_all
for alias in self:
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in __iter__
return iter(self.databases)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 157, in databases
self._databases = settings.DATABASES
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/django19/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This error messages recommends setting `DATABASES` (which is set in `mysite/settings.py`), by defining the variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. So, that's what I did:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="${PWD}/mysite/settings.py"
```

There are also the required `__init__.py` files in the `mysite` and `mysite/mysite` directories. However now when I run the `django-admin` command I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mysite/settings'
```

I can't find anymore documentation or help hereafter. What am I missing? Do I need to set something special somewhere else? Am I setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` correctly? The `ImportError` makes it sound like I should set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `mysite.settings` or something similar, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have created your project, use `manage.py` instead of `django-admin` to run commands:

```
python manage.py shell
```

The `manage.py` command takes care of the settings for you. If you use `django-admin`, you have to set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` manually. The `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should be the Python module, e.g. `mysite.settings`, not a file like `/path/to/mysite/settings.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have your project in the python import search path. Try this

```
>>import sys
>>sys.path
```

if the path/directory for your project is not listed, then you need to do

```
>>sys.path.append('/path/to/my/django/project')
```

Then assign DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE like so:

```
$export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

See [Designating Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings)